# How to keep "schema" of datagridview after DataSource refresh

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I have 2 DataGridViews, it´s a kind of MasterDetail tables. I have a problem with Detail DataGridView called "dgw". It´s DataSource is datatable, `dgw.DataSource=DataTable;`. In code I do some work with columns like change names, add some columns, `dgw.Columns.Add(NewColumn);` change type of column, make some columns not visible etc.

Problem is, that when I set DataSource of dgw again, which is always when the row is changed in Master DataGridView, all my work with columns in dgw is gone and I see "ugly" columns without any changes I made to them.

This is how I refresh DataSource of dgw, code is called on every change of row in MasterDataGridView.

```
dgw.DataSource = typeof(DataTable);
dgw.DataSource = GetVCVDataSource(dataTable);
```

I found some solution and I thought that 1st line should do the work but I probably did not get the idea. Before it was `dgw.DataSource = null;`, I used that to turn off events that happened during datasource assignment.

I believe that there must be some easy solution but I can not work it out.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Why dont you just create method that does formatting to the datagrid and each time you set the DataSource you call that method to reformat the grid?

Comment: Because I am convinced that it is not correct solution. You must do it again and again and again and again... Marc Gravell helped me to find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the first line in there is hurting you; the following would be more appropriate:

```
xx.DataSource = null;
xx.DataSource = GetVCVDataSource(dataTable);
```

Which will rebind without having to worry about a different type in the middle.

Also, at some point earlier (once only):

```
xx.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it is something stupid! It is a part of quiet complex code and I forgot to set up dgw.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
 Btw. it looks like that it does not matter if you set DataSource null or typeof(DataTable), both seems to work well in this case.